# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not LpVariable

Tags: python, list, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm learning python coding and also using pulp to do LP optimization.
I have a function that I need to maximize, but looks like python/pulp won't let my variable browse through list.

```
turbiinit_lista = [0,1,2,3]

prob = LpProblem("Vesivoima", LpMaximize)
k = LpVariable("Test", 0, 3, LpInteger)
```

## maximize this function

```
prob += (10*turbiinit_lista[k])-50-(350*turbiinit_lista[k])


prob.writeLP("Vesivoima.lp")
prob.solve()
```

This is just a simplification of my messy code, but it gives you the idea of my problem.

So is it possible to browses through the list for optimal variable values?

Comment: You cannot use a decision variable as an index (

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO! As @Erwin has pointed out you **cannot** use a decision variable to index into a python list or array.

However you **can** use a MILP via the `pulp` library to select from a list of possible values.

There are a few ways to do this - one is to introduce a list of binary variables to indicate whether each of the options is chosen (variable takes value `1`) or not (variable takes value `0`), and enforce that exactly one of them must be true.

Using this approach your problem would become the following. Note that `choose_vars` are a list of binary decision variables which track which of the list of options is selected, and `chosen_value` is a continuous variable which is constrained to be the chosen value.

```
from pulp import *
turbiinit_lista = [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4]
n = len(turbiinit_lista)
N = range(n)

prob = LpProblem("Vesivoima", LpMaximize)
choose_vars = LpVariable.dicts("choose_%s", N, 0, 1, cat="Integer")
choosen_value = LpVariable("choosen")

prob += (10*choosen_value-50-(350*choosen_value))
prob += choosen_value == lpSum([turbiinit_lista[i]*choose_vars[i] for i in N])
prob += lpSum([choose_vars[i] for i in N]) == 1

prob.writeLP("Vesivoima.lp")
prob.solve()

choose_vars_soln = [choose_vars[i].varValue for i in N]
print("choose_vars_soln: " + str(choose_vars_soln))
print("choosen_value: " + str(choosen_value.varValue))
```

Which outputs:

```
choose_vars_soln: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
choosen_value: 1.1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution was more complicated than I expected, have to examine it. Do you know what to do if I want to do the optimization for multiple periods, like giving the number of periods as an input? --> periods = input("Enter the number of periods")

Comment: It's not too complicated really. Basically in MILPs whenever you need to choose between things you need to use binary variables. Here we have one binary for whether we choose each of the available options or not. There might be a better/neater way though. Having a variable number of periods should be no problem. I'm not sure what the periods are for but it's likely they will end up being another index to the `choose_vars` variables... I.e. we need to choose which to pick in each period...

Comment: By periods I mean like for example two periods --> (10*choosen_value-50-(350*choosen_value)) + (10*choosen_value-50-(350*choosen_value)). Optimizing "choosen_value" for each period but not forgotting the function/big picture uknow. I would later add some constraints.